How to solve $x+1=5e^{4x}$
How to solve $x+1=5e^{4x}$
In general, I know to take ln() of both sides to bring down the exponent for e, but the left side is also a variable.

You need the so-called Lambert W function, and the manipulations get a little complicated.

Ok, so it's doable, just not trivial algebra

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%2B1%3D5e%5E%284*x%29

no nice outcome;  instead  of the $5,$   try $\frac{e^3}{4} \approx 5.02138423 $  so: $$x+1 = \frac{e^3}{4} ; e^{4x} $$

@SeanRoberson I'm not sure if there is a way to even work around the Lambert W function with this, best OP can do is an approximation.

$$x+1=5e^{4x}$$
We see, the equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^{4x}$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to solve the equation by rearranging for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of elementary operations (means elementary functions) we can read from the equation.
According to the theorem in [Lin 1983], the equation doesn't have solutions except $0$ in the real elementary numbers.
But the equation can be solved with Lambert W.
We need a product form. An equation in sum form can be rearranged to a product form in each case.
$$x+1=5e^{4x}$$
$$(x+1)e^{-4x}=5$$
$$-4(x+1)e^{-4x}=-20$$
$$(-4x-4)e^{-4x}=-20$$
$$(-4x-4)e^{-4x}e^{-4}=-20e^{-4}$$
$$(-4x-4)e^{-4x-4}=-20e^{-4}$$
$$-4x-4=W_k(-20e^{-4})\ \ \ \ \ \ (\forall k\in\mathbb{Z})$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{4}W_k(-20e^{-4})-1\ \ \ \ \ \ (\forall k\in\mathbb{Z})$$
For real solutions, the real branches of Lambert W $W_{-1}$ and $W_0$ are needed.

Rewrite the equation like this
$$x+1 = 5e^{4x} = 5e^{4(x+1)-4}$$
$$(x+1)e^{-4(x+1)} = 5e^{-4}$$
$$-4(x+1)e^{-4(x+1)} = -20e^{-4}$$
which has two solutions. There is the standard Lambert-W function
$$W\left(-4(x+1)e^{-4(x+1)}\right) = W\left(-20e^{-4}\right)$$
$$-4(x+1) = W\left(-20e^{-4}\right)$$
$$x = -\frac{1}{4}W\left(-20e^{-4}\right) - 1 \approx -0.7724_\cdots$$
and the other real branch of the Lambert-W, the $-1$ branch
$$W_{-1}\left(-4(x+1)e^{-4(x+1)}\right) = W_{-1}\left(-20e^{-4}\right)$$
$$-4(x+1) = W_{-1}\left(-20e^{-4}\right)$$
$$x = -\frac{1}{4}W_{-1}\left(-20e^{-4}\right) - 1 \approx -0.7262_\cdots$$
Graphically, the two real branches occur whenever you are taking the Lambert-W of a number which lies in the interval $\left(-\frac{1}{e},0\right)$. As seen below, there are two real solutions for such numbers - one on either side of the local minimum of $-\frac{1}{e}$ that occurs at $x=-1$ for the function $f(x) = xe^x$


If you don't have the Lambert W function on your calculator, here is a way to do it. First, note that the exponential function is strictly convex. So, a positively sloped straight line, if it intersects an increasing exponential curve at all, will intersect it just twice (possibly as a tangent). It seems likely that there is a solution near $x=-\frac34$ because, for this value, $f(x):=x+1-5\mathrm e^{4x}=\frac14-5\mathrm e^{-3}$, which is quite small. Let's hunt around near there for solutions:
$$f(-0.7)=0.3-5\mathrm e^{-2.8}\approx-0.00405<0,\\
f(-0.75)=0.25-5\mathrm e^{-3}\approx0.05106>0,\\
f(-0.8)=0.2-5\mathrm e^{-3.2}\approx-0.003811<0,$$
which shows that there are two solutions: one between $-0.8$ and $-0.75$, and one between $-0.75$ and $-0.7$. This suggests two starting points for a Newton iteration: say $x_0=-0.775$ and $x_0=-0.725$. The Newton formula to solve $f(x)=0$ is
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=x_n-\tfrac14-\frac{x_n+\tfrac34}{1-20\exp4x_n}\quad(n=0,1,...).$$
Now (on my calculator) $x_0=-0.775$ gives $x_3=-0.772391135$, while $x_0=-0.725$ yields $x_3=-0.7261864244$, both correct to nine significant figures.
